# Manipulating a linked list from outside of an object

Tags: c++

i want to manipulate a linked list from outside of an object but its not working like i thougt it would be.

This is the situation:
I have a object which has pointer of a base class to a first entry to mark the beginning of a linked list.

```
class theObject {
public:
    theObject() : mFirstEntry(0), mLastEntry(0) {}
    ~theObject() {}

    template<class T>
    void addEntry(const std::string &blah, const std::string &blub, const T &hui)
    {
        child<T> *newEntry = new child<T>(blah, blub, hui);

        if (mFirstEntry) {
            mLastEntry->setNext(newEntry);
            mLastEntry = newEntry;
        }
        else {
            mFirstEntry = newEntry;
            mLastEntry = newEntry;
        }
    }

    base * getFirstEntry() const
    {
        return mFirstEntry;
    }

    void printEntrys() const
    {
        base *data = mFirstEntry;
        while(data) {
            std::cout << data->getBlah() << data->getBlub() << std::endl;
            data = data->getNext();
        }
    }

private:
    base *mFirstEntry;
    base *mLastEntry;
};

class base {
public:
    base() : mBlah(""), mBlub(""), mNext(0) {}

    base(const std::string &blah, const std::string &blub) : mBlah(blah), mBlub(blub), mNext(0) {}

    virtual ~base()
    {
        if (mNext) {
            delete mNext;
        }
    }

    void setNext(base *next)
    {
        mNext = next;
    }

    base * getNext() const
    {
        return mNext;
    }

    std::string getBlah() const
    {
        return mBlah;
    }

    std::string getBlub() const
    {
        return mBlub;
    }

protected:
    std::string mBlah;
    std::string mBlub;
    base *mNext;
};
```

Each entry of the linked list is of the type child which is a template and inherits the base class.

```
template<class T>
class child : public base {
public:
    inline child(const std::string &blah, const std::string &blub, const T &hui, base *next = 0) : mHui(hui), base(blah, blub)
    {
        if(next) {
            mNext = next;
        }
    }

    inline child(const child &r)
    {
        *this = r;
    }

    inline const child & operator = (const child &r)
    {
        if (this == &r) return *this;

        mBlah = r.mBlah;
        mBlub = r.mBlub;
        mNext = r.mNext;
        mHui = r.mHui;

        return *this;
    }

    inline const T getData() const
    {
        return mHui;
    }

protected:
    T mHui;
};
```

Now i am filling the object with a couple of entries

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    theObject data;
    int a(0), b(1), c(2), d(3);
    const std::string blah("blah"), blub("blub");
    data.addEntry(blah, blub, a);
    data.addEntry(blah, blub, b);
    data.addEntry(blah, blub, c);
    data.addEntry(blah, blub, d);

    std::cout << "Original entries" << std::endl;
    data.printEntrys();
```

Then i want to maipulate the linked list

```
    base *stuff = data.getFirstEntry();
    std::cout << "Changed in stuff list" << std::endl;
    while(stuff) {
        stuff = new child<double>("noBlah", "noBlub", 3.14, stuff->getNext());
        std::cout << stuff->getBlah() << stuff->getBlub() << std::endl;
        stuff = stuff->getNext();
    }
```

And hoped to manipulate the original...but it seams i manipulated only a copy

```
    std::cout << "linked list in data object should now be stuff list" << std::endl;
    data.printEntrys();

    return 0;
}
```

Does anybode has an idea why its not working? getFirstEntry() returns a pointer so i thought i would manipulate the object its pointing to.

Best regards,
Ben

Comment: You could have cut a *lot* of code out of this example, and still demonstrated the problem.

Comment: Well that may be true but it was the closesd to our code. I thought that maybee the template child class could be an issue. I try next time to get it smaler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to ntor i was able to sole the issue.

this is the code example (the code from the beginning is still valid)

```
template<class T>
child<T> * getnewEntry(const std::string &a, const std::string &b, const T &c, base *next)
{
    child<T> *nc= new child<T>(a, b, c, next);
    return nc;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    theObject data;
    int a(0), b(1), c(2), d(3);
    const std::string blah("blah"), blub("blub");
    data.addEntry(blah, blub, a);
    data.addEntry(blah, blub, b);
    data.addEntry(blah, blub, c);
    data.addEntry(blah, blub, d);

    base *stuff = data.getFirstEntry();
    stuff = getnewEntry("noBlah", "noBlub", 3.14, stuff->getNext());
    data.mFirstEntry->setNext(0);
    delete data.mFirstEntry;
    data.mFirstEntry = stuff;

    while (stuff->getNext()) {
        base *tmpstuff = getnewEntry("noBlah", "noBlub", 3.14, stuff->getNext()->getNext());
        stuff->getNext()->setNext(0);
        delete stuff->getNext();
        stuff->setNext(tmpstuff);
        stuff = tmpstuff;
    }

    data.mLastEntry = stuff;

    return 0;
}
```

This is now changing the object at a position of a linked list and updating the linked list

Answer (score 0):

You get a pointer to the first element via `base *stuff = data.getFirstEntry();`, then point it to a new object instead with `stuff = new child<double>("noBlah", "noBlub", 3.14, stuff->getNext());`. In other words, you change the pointer, not the value pointed to.

I would recommend you review a tutorial on pointers. Someone once recommended this video: [Binky Pointer Fun](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/)

Comment: Haha, this Binky Pointer stuff is hilarious :D  I think it's weird I laugh about stuff like that... I should make a coding pause for a moment :-/

Answer (score 0):

You return a pointer and change the **local** pointer, without changing the value the pointer points on!
You should do:

```
*stuff = child<double>("noBlah", "noBlub", 3.14, stuff->getNext());
```

On this way you would actually change the object the pointer points on.

LG ntor

Comment: Hm ok that sounds logical. But afterwards the link is destroyed and the next entry is a bad pointer

Comment: Why? The previous is still pointing on the same adress and the pointer is set by `getNext()` by taking over the old adress, isn't it?

Comment: yes, till it left the = operator by returning *this everything is fine, but then its a bad pointer

Comment: No, look that I'm not doing `new child....`, but `child....`. And therefore the pointer `stuff` isn't even touched. It will use the `operator=(const child&)` that is declared in the child class.

Comment: yes that is what i am doing as well:base *stuff = data.getFirstEntry();
 while(stuff) {
  *stuff = getnewEntry("noBlah", "noBlub", 3.14, stuff->getNext());
  stuff = stuff->getNext();
 }

Comment: with newEntry returning child<T>(a, b, c, next);

Comment: afterwards the linked list is destroyed but i dont know why